# How to redirect to a controller function in jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to change the form action based on the selected value from a dropdown menu.Based on the selection i want to redirect my function to two different controller functions.But in my code redirection is not working.Can any one please help me to solve this problem.My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $("#sub").click(function () {    
            var usertype = $("#user").val();

            if (usertype == 'client') {                              
                window.location.href = "<?php  echo site_url('client_login/clogin'); ?>";
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "<?php  echo base_url('hospital.php'); ?>";
            }      
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is your `js file` or `php file` ??

Comment: How you run php code in js file??

Answer (score 0):

I'll need other related components like your view to be sure. But based on what's available.

Try this in your View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#sub").click(function () {    
        var usertype = $("#user");
        var selectedUserType = usertype.options[usertype.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selectedUserType == 'client') {    

            window.location = "<?php  echo site_url('client_login/clogin'); ?>";
        }
        else {
            //redirect to another controller
        }      
    });     
});
```

Try checking your code step by step by placing alerts. Like checking if your click function is even getting called, or if the valued selected is actually the right one, and so on...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#sub").click(function () {    
        var usertype = $("#user").val();

        if (usertype == 'client') {                              
            window.location.replace("<?php  echo base_url('client_login/clogin'); ?>");
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace("<?php  echo base_url('controller_name/hospital'); ?>");
        }      
    });     
 });
</script>
```

If you are using codeigniter then you have to call controller/function. In your else condition you wrote direct hospital.php.

You should also use window.location=url;

I hope this will help you :)